# Generalization of certain interactions with non-muslims

Tags: fiqh, hadith-interpretation, non-muslim

It is narrated in https://sunnah.com/muslim:2167a:

> Do not greet the Jews and the Christians before they greet you and when you meet any one of them on the roads force him to go to the narrowest part of it.

From the explanations I've heard, this was in a specific situation when they were marching to the tribe of Qurayzah. However;

It is narrated in https://sunnah.com/abudawud:5205:

> Suhayl ibn AbuSalih said: I went out with my father to Syria. The people passed by the cloisters in which there were Christians and began to salute them. My father said: Do not give them salutation first, for Abu Hurayrah reported the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) as saying: Do not salute them (Jews and Christians) first, and when you meet them on the road, force them to go to the narrowest part of it.

According to this narration, it shares the same details in the 2nd part, and in the 1st part, it provides a little bit more context. In this narration, it mentions that Suhayl ibn Abu Salih narrated from Abu Hurayrah, that sahih muslim 2167 was to be used in his situation as well. Yet, his situation had nothing to do with meeting the Jews and Christians in battle, in fact, they were in Syria and a couple of Christians passed by and he felt that the narration in sahih muslim 2167 was almost general, and he narrated it on accordance of Abu Hurayrah. My question is, is the first narration meant to be generalized and secondly, what do we make of the second narration I posted? From the looks of it, it provides a bit of context, and the context generalizes sahih muslim 2167 in accordance to a companion himself. Am I missing something? I truly feel like I am because this feels very out of ordinary to be generalized in an Islamic narrative. How else is one supposed to send peace and show the good character of what it means to be a Muslim?

Answer (score 2):

The hadith is understood to be general by the majority of the scholars. You can see that the hadith is compiled in Sahih Muslim under a chapter titled:

> Chapter: The Prohibition Of Initiating The Greeting With The People Of The Book, And How To Respond To Them

And not under a chapter on history of battles.

Initiating greeting to a disbeliever by saying  السلام عليكم - even if the disbeliever is a Dhimmi - is makruh according to the [Hanafis](https://shamela.ws/book/21613/3854) and [Malikis](https://shamela.ws/book/21589/744), haram according to the [Shafi'is](https://shamela.ws/book/11444/2745) and [Hanbalis](https://shamela.ws/book/622/3079).

A Muslim is not supposed to show honor or affection towards a disbeliever. Rather they are humbled and disgraced because of their kufr.

Comment: Except, just because Muslim titled it this way, doesn't necessarily imply that it's general either. Likewise, even if it is to be understood generally, he's not a certified authority, even if his tradition is sahih. Also, the sources you sent for both Hanafi and Maliki don't show any other evidences besides the evidences you have already provided. The whole answer feels very misleading because you aren't providing the other side to the picture as well. Lastly, the logic behind this doesn't make sense. If one has a non-muslim wife for example, or a non-muslim mother, you aren't supposed to...

Comment: show affection towards them because of their kufr, because they are to be humbled and disgraced? You aren't providing a full picture here dude. I'd appreciate if you'd refrain from responding to any of my questions unless you provide a complete picture with proper sources as well.